# PrestaShop 1.6 : Show module contents on CMS page (center column)

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am new to **PrestaShop** working on **1.6.0.9** version. I have developed one module to manage news. It have 5 fields- news title, news details, news image, news status and news publish date. The module works perfectly at back office. Now I want to show all the news created in this module on the front side. Please see the image below:

[image: Header Menu]

This is my header menu. It is having last option as **Press** which is currently a CMS page. Now I want the contents of my news module to be shown on this page, rather than the contents added from CMS block module.

First of all, is it possible? If yes, is there any way to do this or any suggestions or modifications?

If no, is there any alternate way to show the module contents on front office on a separate page on menu option click?

Thank you for your time to read the question. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you, try to display it in a separate page instead of cms page and add a url link in blocktopmenu.

You can create a front page easily in few steps

**Step - 1: Create a front controller**

let your module name is **Blockexample**

your directory structure is 
*module/module_name/controllers/front/controller_name.php*

i.e.,
"module/blockexample/controllers/front/test.php"

**class name convention must follow as below:**

class modulename+controllername+ModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController()

eg: Blockexample+Test+ModuleFrontController

Create a test controller in the above path and add below code.

```
class BlockexampleTestModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

public function init()
{
    $this->page_name = 'testpage'; // page_name and body id
    $this->display_column_left = false; // hides left column
    parent::init();
}

public function initContent()
{
     parent::initContent();
     //path for displaying in breadcrumb, use this array to pass values to view file
     $this->context->smarty->assign(array('path'=>'Test')); 
     $this->setTemplate('test.tpl');
}

//for linking your css and javascript    
public function setMedia() 
{
    parent::setMedia();
    $this->addCSS(__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.$this->module->name.'/css/'.$this->module->name.'.css');
    $this->addJS(__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.$this->module->name.'/js/'.$this->module->name.'.js');    
}

}
```

**Step - 1 : Create a view**

Your view directory structure is

module/module_name/views/templates/front/file_name.tpl

i.e, "module/blockexample/views/templates/front/test.tpl"

Now create a tpl file in above path and add just "hello world".

**Step - 3: Access your module in front end**

Now open the link in browser

**url format:**
http://domain.com/index.php?fc=module&module=module_name&controller=controller_name

eg: 
  www.example.com/index.php?fc=module&module=blockexample&controller=test

Now you can add your link in the above format and create a new link in blocktopmenu in your backoffice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @DSP. I will try the steps mentioned hereby and let you know..

Comment: Its going to 404 - Page not available

Comment: Did you created the front controller and view in your module? If the 404 error coming after creating the front controller and view. Just delete the class_index.php in the cache folder of your shop and try reload the page.
i.e, prestashop/cache/class_index.php

Comment: Thank you so much for the startup to the solution for my problem. Finally I got what I wanted.

Comment: One more small help, if possible. It is continuously showing the error `headers already sen` How to get rid of it

Comment: Thank you @Suyog, I am glad It help you

Comment: can attach the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91236/discussion-between-suyog-and-dsp).

Comment: Check whether you included any library/includes in your controller. I think the class you included in your controller is already included. For eg: session